Alerts() trigger continuously once condition is met until limit reached
I've tried to write some code that allows indicator alerts to trigger multiple times with a bar but not more than once in a row in the same direction using a check. However when the condition is met, which is a simple crossover or crossunder, the alerts trigger continuously until the limit for number of alerts within a 3 minute period is reached.
Any help would be much appreciated
var bool shortAlertTriggered = false
var bool longAlertTriggered = false

 
if shortCondition and not shortAlertTriggered
    alert("Short condition met", alert.freq_all)
    shortAlertTriggered := true   
    longAlertTriggered := false   

if longCondition and not longAlertTriggered
    alert("Long condition met", alert.freq_all)
    longAlertTriggered := true  
    shortAlertTriggered := false 

plotshape(shortCondition, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red,          text="Short Alert")
plotshape(longCondition, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="Long Alert")


What are shortCondition and longCondition?

var bool shortAlertTriggered = false
var bool longAlertTriggered = false

This article may be helpful:

Whereas scripts only execute once at the close of historical bars, when a script is running in realtime, it executes every time the chart’s feed detects a price or volume update.
At every realtime update, Pine Script™‘s runtime normally resets the values of a script’s variables to their last committed value, i.e., the value they held when the previous bar closed. This is generally handy, as each realtime script execution starts from a known state, which simplifies script logic.
Sometimes, however, script logic requires code to be able to save variable values between different executions in the realtime bar. Declaring variables with varip makes that possible. The “ip” in varip stands for intrabar persist.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/language/variable-declarations/#varip
